# Symbol index sorted by occurrence

Tags: indexing, sorting

I would like to make an symbol index which is sorted by occurence of symbol.

For example: Something like

```
... $\omega$\index{$\omega$} ... $A^P_k$\index{$A^P_k$} ... $\{\}$\index{$\{\}$}
```

should produce an index which first mentions `$\omega$` then `$A^P_k$` and then `$\{\}$`.

I did not find any option for `makeidx`, so I tried to use a workaround and define a command which does that for me:

```
\newcounter{occurrence}
\newcommand{\is}[1]{\index{\arabic{occurrence}@{#1}}\addtocounter{occurrence}{1}}
```

In fact this works to some extend but some symbols get rejected (I do not know which one) and some will not be printed appropriate for example `\is{$\langle \rangle$}` results in the entry "hAB".

Comment: You find a transcript of MakeIndex workings in the `.ilg` file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that `\index` expands its contents when it appears as the argument to another command, while it doesn't if it appears at the top level, so with `\is{$\langle\rangle$}` you get, in the `.idx` file,

```
\indexentry{0@{$\delimiter "426830A \delimiter "526930B $}}{1}
```

and, in the `.ind` file,

```
\item {$\delimiter 426830A \delimiter 526930B $}, 1
```

(notice that the double quotes get lost).

Now TeX finds `\delimiter` followed by the number 426830, which is hexadecimal `"6834E` and since it's in normal operations, it typesets the math code `"0068`: in position `"68` of font family 0 there's an h. Similarly, 526930 is hexadecimal `"80A52`, but in position `"80` there's no character! So you get a roman h, followed by italics A and B. Wow!

A way out is telling TeX not to interpret the characters:

```
\newcommand{\is}[1]{%
  \index{\arabic{occurrence}@\detokenize{#1}}%
  \stepcounter{occurrence}}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can control the order of the things in the index by providing some additional information to the argument of the `\index` command.

By writing `\index{<sort information by>@<information>}`, you tell `\index` to put  `<information>` in the index but sort it by `<sort information by>`.

For example, using the following:

- `\index{.a omega@$\omega$}`
- `\index{.a alpha@$\alpha$}`
- `\index{.b APK@$A^P_k$}`
- `\index{.c \{\}@$\{\}$}`
- `\index{a}`
- `\index{A}`

The entries in the index should be as follows:

- $\alpha$;
- $\omega$;
- $A^P_k$;
- ${}$;
- A;
- a.

In this example, I use `.` as a prefix for index material with mathematical content (it effectively forces the mathematical stuff before the letters), and `<letter>` as a presorting criterion.

The following shows how to adjust the `\index` command to make it 'sort' the indexes by occurrence. This solution is equivalent to the [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41140/symbol-index-sorted-by-occurrence#41144) that was posted by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg).

```
\makeatletter

\newcount\index@counter
\let\old@index\index
\def\myindex@#1#2{%
    \old@index{#1@#2}%
}
\def\index#1{%
    \expandafter\myindex@{\the\index@counter}{#1}%
    \advance \index@counter by 1\relax
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possibility that uses `glossaries`. You need an up-to-date version of `glossaries`, but you don't need to use `makeindex` or any other external application. Just run LaTeX twice.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[index]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newterm[name={\ensuremath{\omega}}]{omega}
\newterm[name={\ensuremath{A^P_k}}]{Apk}
\newterm[name={\ensuremath{\{\}}}]{braces}

\begin{document}
\gls{omega} 

\gls{Apk} 

\gls{braces}

\printnoidxglossary[type=index,style=mcolindex,sort=use]
\end{document}
```

Of if you find `\ensuremath` abhorrent:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[index]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newterm[name={$\omega$},text={\omega}]{omega}
\newterm[name={$A^P_k$},text={A^P_k}]{Apk}
\newterm[name={$\{\}$},text={\{\}}]{braces}

\begin{document}
$\gls{omega}$

$\gls{Apk}$

$\gls{braces}$

\printnoidxglossary[type=index,style=mcolindex,sort=use]
\end{document}
```