# Problem with \index in align environment

Tags: amsmath, align, indexing, imakeidx

Please compile the following MWE. As you will then see, the typesetting of `$\mu^{\otimes\downarrow n}$` in the index is strange!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\begin{align}\index{$\mu^{\otimes\downarrow n}$}
x
\end{align}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

NB: No problem for `equation` instead of `align` or if `$\index{$\mu^{\otimes\downarrow n}$}$` is placed before `\begin{align}`.

What's wrong here?

Comment: I can confirm this.  The `idx` file contains `\delimiter "3223379`, which prints as a large bracket, instead of `\downarrow`.  This occurs for other AMS environments including `gather` and `multline`, but as @lpdbw says it is fine for `equation`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally the argument of `\index` is read verbatim, but ams alignments act like command arguments and defeat verbatim so the argument is read as command tokens and the entry expands to

```
 \indexentry{$\mu ^{\otimes \delimiter "3223379 n}$}{1}
```

which messes up the index. You could use

```
\index{$\mu^{\otimes\protect\downarrow n}$}
```

which would work, but produces different index entry to the command when used in equation or other normal environments. Probably the simplest way to ensure that all uses of this produce the same index entry is to use

```
\mbox{\index{$\mu^{\otimes\protect\downarrow n}$}}
```

where the `\mbox` is just there to force the argument into a macro argument so that the verbatim processing is turned off consistently.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand why `\downarrow` is transfomed into `\delimiter "3223379`!?

Comment: That's its definition:-) plain tex defines `\def\downarrow{\delimiter"3223379 }`  The hex number tells TeX which font(s) to extract the symbol from at normal and large sizes

Comment: latex defines it as `\DeclareMathDelimiter{\downarrow}
   {\mathrel}{symbols}{"23}{largesymbols}{"79}` which is easier to read but it makes the same definition in the end.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41144/4427

Comment: @egreg, oh it's an exact duplicate. Still This one has a title that makes it more likely it would be found again I doubt anyone but you (remembering your previous answer) would have spotted that:-) "wow" yes it's pretty amazing it goes through so many wrong expansions and produces something that produces output at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's not really an exact duplicate; but also in this case I'd recommend something like `\index{...@...}` for correct alphabetizing. If you try `\index{\detokenize{$\mu^{\otimes\downarrow n}$}}` there will be spaces after the control sequences.

Comment: To get the same index entry `\indexentry{$\mu^{\otimes\downarrow n}$}{...}`
is written by `\index{$\mu^{\otimes\downarrow n}$}`, if `\index` can read its argument in verbatim manner (outside of `align`),
or by `\index{$\string\mu^{\string\otimes\protect\downarrow n}$}`, if `\index` and its argument is already read before `\index`
is executed (inside `align` or `\mbox`). `\string` does not append a space after a control sequence name, but `\protect` or `\detokenize` do.

Comment: yes the spaces issue is why I suggested using the `\protect` in argument form (so you get the same spaces always), `\detokenize` is essentially the same thing (or at least, has the same issues). I agree though for any symbolic entry using a `@` field to help the sorting is wise.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek yes I thought about suggesting that but decided it was simpler to suggest turning off verbatim and using the same argument everywhere (then it doesn't really matter so much about whether spaces are added as they are added consistently)

Comment: @David Carlisle: OK, I understand your above comment about the definition of `\downarrow` in LaTeX and plain TeX. Just why then does this definition produce something else in in the index? I certainly missed something in your explanations ...

Comment: See egreg's great answer in the link from his comment. basically the `"` means hex-number in Tex but (by default) it is a quote character for makeindex, so it quotes the next thing, which is a digit, which just produces itself, so makeindex carries on but produces something without the `"` which then gets interpreted by TeX as a decimal number and anything that happens after that is purely accidental....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Then I would consider something like `\newcommand*{\Index}[1]{\index{\detokenize{#1}}}` to avoid trouble with macro expansion.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, Good plan.