# \{ & \} vs \lbrace & \rbrace

Tags: math-mode, braces

So, what is the difference in using `\{` and `\}` to using `\lbrace` and `\rbrace`?
Which one is preferred, and when one has to take care?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From the LaTeX kernel (`latex.ltx`):

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\{}{\ifmmode\lbrace\else\textbraceleft\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\}}{\ifmmode\rbrace\else\textbraceright\fi}
```

Thus differences:

- `\{` and `\}` work in both text and math mode, `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` only in math mode. The latter macros trigger an error in text mode.
- `\{` and `\}` are shorter (two characters instead of seven).
- `\{` and `\}` are robust commands. For the discussion of the robustness of
  `\lbrace` and `\rbrace`, see below.
- `\{` and `\}` might be better supported by editors (matching support, see comment of jjdb).

Similarities:

- In math mode both variants execute `\lbrace` and `\rbrace`.
- The same math spacing.

`\lbrace` and `\rbrace` are defined in `fontmath.ltx`, also part of the LaTeX kernel (see [source2e.pdf](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf)):

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}
   {\mathopen}{symbols}{"66}{largesymbols}{"08}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rceil}
   {\mathclose}{symbols}{"65}{largesymbols}{"07}
```

They are defined as (`\show\lbrace`/`\show\rbrace`):

```
\def\lbrace{\delimiter "4266308 }
\def\rbrace{\delimiter "5267309 }
```

And `\delimiter` is a unexpandable TeX primitive. It is followed by `"` and a number, both with catcodes `12` (other, unexpandable). And the space at the end is not expandable either. If the characters are reread, e.g. in the table of contents, then the quote character `"` might cause trouble, if it is used as active character. For example, if someone defines a `babel` shorthand `"4` or `"5`.

Answer to the comment of `egreg` referring to [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41144/4427) to an index question. The quote character `"` has a special meaning for index entries.
(With the default meaning `"4` or `"5` become `4` or `5` in the index, the
quote character gets lost.) This can happen if `\index` is used in an argument of another command. Otherwise `\index` reads its argument with verbatim catcodes,
thus macros are not expanded.

Comment: another pro for me - using `VIM` - is to jump  from  `{` to the corresponding `}` by pressing % ;)

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find out what 'expandable' means?

Comment: It's not really true that `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` are "robust": check http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41144/4427 for a similar problem with `\langle` and `\rangle`

Comment: So, AFAIU there are no downsides using `\{` & `\}`? So one should then always stick to them?

Comment: @egreg But `\{` and `\}` are robust?

Comment: @jjdb Yes, they are.

Comment: @egreg So what needs to be changed in the answer of Heiko Oberdiek to make it correct?

Comment: @egrep The [index issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41144/4427) is different matter than LaTeX's robustness. Otherwise would you consider characters such as `!`, `@`, ... as *fragile*? But you are right that `"` might cause trouble, if `"` is an active character (`babel`, ...).

Comment: @jjdb Answer updated.