# Indexing an argument to a new command produces odd results

Tags: indexing

Consider this basic .tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, draft]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\newcommand{\withIndex}[1]{#1\index{$#1$}}
\newcommand{\myIndex}[1]{\index{$#1$}}
\begin {document}
\section{Test section}

Some test text \index{text}.

A $\Downarrow$ \index{$\Downarrow$} represents....\\
Another \withIndex{$\Downarrow$} represents...\\
Perhaps $\Downarrow$ \myIndex{$\Uparrow$} represents...\
\printindex
\end {document}
```

I have the `\withIndex` command defined on line 4 in my document, and it works well for the majority of symbols. However, when certain symbols are used with this command odd results are produced. Calling `\withIndex($\Downarrow$}` in the document body puts the key `${\Gamma}B37F$` into the index (to give another example, indexing `$\langle$` in this way gives the key 'hA').

Naturally, I want to see the `\Downarrow` symbol appear in the index (or the left angled bracket in my other example). The `\myIndex` command produces the same result, but `\index{$\Downarrow$}` gives the correct output. Why do I get such strange index output for these particular symbols with the `\withIndex` command?

Comment: This question is very similar to [Symbol index sorted by occurrence](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41140/). Look if it helps you.

Comment: You shouldn't add `$` in the definition of `\myIndex` and `\withIndex`, though, if you plan to call `\withIndex{$\Downarrow$}`, because this would result in `$$` in the index file.

Comment: Ah yes indeed, thanks for pointing that out. I'll make that edit in my file.