# How to escape | character in \index?

Tags: hyperref, indexing

While `|` is the `encap` character for `makeindex`, then if I want to use `|` in `\index`, e.g. `\index{$|F|$}`, how to escape it?

When I escape it with double quote, i.e. `\index{$"|F"|$}`, and use `hyperref`, the *.idx file will looks like

```
\indexentry{$"|hyperindexformat{\F"}}{1}
```

which results an error.

Comment: `\index{$"|F"|$}` should do.

Comment: @egreg but when I use `hyperref`, the *.idx file looks like: `\indexentry{$"|hyperindexformat{\F"}}{1}`, which results in an error.

Answer (score 4):

In theory, a character that is special for MakeIndex, for instance `!`, `|`, `@` should be quoted with `"`. However, this confuses `hyperref` when `|` is used.

The workaround is simple:

```
\index{$\vert F\vert$}
```

or, better, loading `amsmath` and using an alphabetizing string:

```
\index{Fabs@$\lvert F\rvert$}
```

Using `\lvert` and `\rvert` is recommended anyway.

You can also load `mathtools` and do

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{|}{|}
```

and use `$\abs{F}$` (look at the package documentation for more information).

The `\abs` strategy is better for another reason: if `\index` appears in the argument to another command, such as

```
\newcommand\keyword[1]{\underline{\bfseries #1}\index{#1}}
```

and then called as

```
\keyword{$\vert F\vert$}
```

the `\vert` command is expanded (see [Symbol index sorted by occurrence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41140/symbol-index-sorted-by-occurrence) for a similar case). If you use `\abs`, this won't happen.

Note: `\bf` is a deprecated command; I changed the definition you showed in the comment to be in line with the recommended practice.

Comment: If I define a new command wrapping `\index`, why `\index` will be affected: `\newcommand\keyword[1]{\bf\underline{#1}\index{#1}}`, e.g. `\keyword{$\vert F\vert$}` not work

Comment: @MartinWang That's another known problem. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41140/symbol-index-sorted-by-occurrence You don't get it with the `\abs` route.