# How do I prepare an index of symbols with memoir?

Tags: memoir, indexing, sorting

I want to prepare an index of symbols for a book I'm writing (using the `memoir` class).  There is an obvious problem of how you order the symbols.  Since many of them are non-alphabetic, I think that the order of appearance in the book is the best idea.  I skimmed through the man page for `makeindex`, but didn't find any option for that (and I don't want to do things like `\index{01@symbol}`, `\index{02@symbol}` etc., for obvious reasons).

Bonus points for a solution where non-alphabetic symbols appear first (as a group), sorted in the order of appearance, and alphabetic ones after them, sorted lexicographically, like in

```
Symbols
=
<
(,)

A
angle
apple
arrgh

B
Banach space
banana
```

Comment: Do something like `\index{aaaaaaa\arabic{symbolcounter} @\somesymbol}\stepcounter{symbolcounter}`?

Comment: Thanks!  I thought about it, too, but some time after posting the question.  It might work, and if there's no package doing this, I'll probably end up writing one. ;)

Comment: Ha, I found out that my question is mostly duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41140/5626 .

Comment: Under that post egreg explained "hAB" without an implement. And Marc van Dongen gave an answer producing duplicated symbol-items.

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicated"?  (I didn't test the solutions there.)

Comment: if you say `\index{cos}` twice it produces two "cos"'s in your index. And if you start the counter from `1`, you cannot predict which goes first: `1`, `13`, or `123`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

**Explaination**

- `\newsymbol{cos}` gives this symbol (`$\cos$`) an unique id (= current value of `symbolcounter`). This number is stored in the macro `symbolidofcos`.
- `\symbolindex{cos}` check whether this symbol appeared before. If not, it does `\newsymbol{cos}`. It then, no matter the symbol being new or old, writes informations into the index.
- Symbols will be sorted according to their ids. Since ids are given in sequences, symbols will be shown in the order of their first appearances.

Here is the code

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{makeidx}
    \makeindex
    \newcounter{symbolcounter}\setcounter{symbolcounter}{1000}
    \newcommand*\newsymbol[1]{
        \stepcounter{symbolcounter}
        \expandafter\edef\csname symbolidof#1\endcsname{\arabic{symbolcounter}}}
    \newcommand*\symbolindex[1]{
        \ifcsname symbolidof#1\endcsname\else\newsymbol{#1}\fi
        \index{~@(Symbols)!\csname symbolidof#1\endcsname @$\csname#1\endcsname$}}
\begin{document}
    \index{Lorem}
    $\sin\theta$\symbolindex{sin}
    \index{ipsum}
    $\cos\theta$\symbolindex{cos}
    \index{dolor}
    $\tan\theta$\symbolindex{tan}
    \index{sit}
\clearpage
    \index{amet}
    $\cos\phi$\symbolindex{cos}
    \index{consectetur}
    $\cosh\phi$\symbolindex{cosh}
    \index{adipiscing}
\printindex
\end{document}
```