# Create Index using macros and |-character

Tags: macros, indexing

I'm currently creating an index for mathmatical symbols used in my document, including the use of the `|`-symbol. To make things easier, I added a macro to be changed easily, but this creates a problem for `$f|_A$`

This is a minimal (not) working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\mathsymbol}[2]{#2\index{#1@#2}}

\begin{document}

\mathsymbol{f}{$f\vert_A$}

$f\vert_A$\index{a@$f\vert_A$}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

As far as I know, the macro should expand to the the line below. In the text, everything is fine, but the index is different: while the line without the macro works as expected, the other entry looks like `$f\GammaA30C_A$`.

The accompanying `.idx`-file contains

```
\indexentry{f@$f\delimiter "026A30C _A$}{1}
\indexentry{a@$f\vert_A$}{1}
```

Thus, how can I create an index with a macro including this special case, without the `|` beeing substituted by this (hex?)-code?

I use these commands:

```
$ lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017/Arch Linux)
$ makeindex
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2017] (kpathsea + Thai support).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is similar to [Symbol index sorted by occurrence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41140/4427)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\mathsymbol}[2]{#2\index{#1@\detokenize{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\mathsymbol{f}{$f\vert_A$}

$f\vert_A$\index{a@$f\vert_A$}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't have found this question. Thanks a lot!