# \index with see macro and math content

Tags: makeindex

Following a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451882/why-does-newcommand-not-work-properly-with-index-and-math-argument), I have problems with giving the see macro (from makeidx) math input. The MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Test
\index{\string{$\mu$-recursive}}\index{recursive|see \string{$mu$-recursive}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The error messages in line 3 and 7:
Something like "Extra } or missing \endgroup".

What is the problem? As shown in the source code, I already evaluated the math content later by using \string.

Comment: I’m going to remove my answer (although you have accepted it) because it is wrong.  The correct answer, however, is longer, and I cannot anticipate when I’ll have the time to write it.  But perhaps someone else will answer in my place! :-)

Comment: It looks like I cannot delete an accepted answer: please “un-accept” it, because, I repeat, it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `\string` is completely wrong.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Test\index{mu-recursive@$\mu$-recursive}\index{recursive|see {$\mu$-recursive}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Note how the format `sort@entry` is used for helping MakeIndex to correctly sort a non alphabetic entry.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`\string` is not like a command with an argument: with `\string{` you are actually turning the opening brace into an ordinary character, thus making the ensuing `}` unbalanced.  On the other hand, for the purpose of writing to a file, in this particular context you don’t need `\string` at all, since all the tokens that you want to write, *including* `\mu`, happen to be unexpandable:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Test: \texttt{\meaning\mu}%
\index{$\mu$-recursive}\index{recursive|see{$\mu$-recursive}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

In general, however, you shouldn’t use `\string`, but rather `\protect`: indeed, the latter can be safely applied to unexpandable tokens, while, at the same time, inhibiting premature expansion of expandable ones.  In other words, unlike `\string`, `\protect` doesn’t require you to know the type (expandable vs. unexpandable) of the control sequence you want to apply it to.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Test: \texttt{\meaning\mu}%
\index{$\protect\mu$-recursive}\index{recursive|see{$\protect\mu$-recursive}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my specific original case, I tried this strateg once, but apparently did not generate new index files with makeindex,. Instead I trusted in TeXWorks "Remove Aux files...", which did not remove the faulty Ind files. The problem is solved. Thank you!